# Which databases Laravel supports and how can I add another one?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, laravel

Based on some researches, I'm sure Laravel supports `MySQL`, `SQLite`, `PostgreSQL` by default. I mean we can just simply replace one of those database names with this:

[image]

Well I have two related questions:

1. Isn't there any list of all databases that Laravel supports by defaul? For example what about `SQL Server`? Can I just replace `sqlserver` with `mysql`, then does it work? In other word Does Laravel know `sqlserver` by default?
2. How can I add a new database to Laravel? For example *(suppose `sqlserver` is not supported in Laraver by defaul)* so how can I add `sqlserver` to Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Laravel 5.3 supports four databases:

1. MySQL
2. Postgres
3. SQLite
4. SQL Server (Driver 'sqlsrv')

Refer [Laravel Docs - Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)

Adding a new Database will always going to take great amount of efforts. Because you will need to write at least whole DB Façade (Forget about the Eloquent ORM Support) to maintain the cleanliness and ease of Laravel Framework.

This includes basic CRUD , database structures & Schema and Eloquent model and Query builder with support for your Database.

As Laravel supports most used SQL and No-SQL Databases by default, there are plenty of open source libraries for other databases, too.

For Example, [Laravel MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) is a good open source library built using Laravel Core APIs.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question, please accept it as best answer ;)

Comment: I'd just like to add that MariaDB is also supported, as a drop-in replacement for MySQL with the same driver. :)

Comment: Laravel supports MariaDB with same MySQL configurations, with same driver. But Prior to Feb, '16, It was not supported in Homestead. Though, it is now and designed to be a drop-in replacement and includes many features over MySQL. This means your code base doesn’t need to change, and tools like Sequel Pro can still be used even though it’s not officially supported.